# batch copy files, perform operation and copy more files

Tags: python

I want to copy files from a directory in batch mode, perform an operation on the copied files and then copy more files. To do this I have managed this code

```
import os
import sys
from shutil import copy2

_, _, filenames = next(os.walk("src/"))

print(filenames)
number_of_files = len(filenames)
batch_number = 2
i = 0
while i < number_of_files:
    i += 1
    j = i + batch_number
    print(filenames[i:j])
```

and its output is

```
['file_02', 'file_03']
['file_03', 'file_04']
['file_04', 'file_010']
['file_010', 'file_01']
['file_01', 'file_06']
['file_06', 'file_08']
['file_08', 'file_09']
['file_09', 'file_07']
['file_07']
[]
```

What I want is:

```
['file_01', 'file_02']
['file_03', 'file_04']
['file_05', 'file_06']
['file_07', 'file_08']
['file_09', 'file_10']
```

What would be the best way to go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be careful, `os.walk` doesn't provide sorting in numerical way.
You can use `sort()` method. And pass each time to certain list, where you sort the content numerically

```
you_file_list.sort(key=int)
```

Since you case contain `file` name, you can put `file_` to `XX` number in `filenames` list.